# find duplicate photos based on similarity threshold on linux

Tags: duplicates, imagemagick, photo, similarity

I have 2 TB of photos with a lot of "similar" duplicates. Like they are smaller versions or lower quality.

I've seen numerous GUI tools for finding duplicates but I don't like the way they work.

I'm trying to find a way to dump all duplicates based on a similarity threshold, along with the % similar.

`findimagedupes` works but it does not print the `% similar`.

I see `imagemagic` is the internet favorite but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it to print the % difference between two pictures.

Comment: See perceptual hash in Imagemagick. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/perceptual_hash_test_results_510/index.html

Comment: Oh that is so much technical reading. Let me give this a try. Thank you!